# Java: Running task at different intervals

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I want to run the same task periodically, but at different intervals.
e.g. for (1s, 2s, 3s) method should be called after 1s, 3s, 6s, 7s and so on.

Usually I use `scheduleAtFixedRate`, but with the same time between calls. Thanks!

Comment: does the task finish within 1sec?

Comment: Have u considered scenario where the task takes more than one second, do u want next task to be started in that case or wait for previous one to finish

Comment: It think that 1s sec it's more then enough for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scedule task execution at 1sec rate and make the task itself to skip unwanted times

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution, without other any dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz with cron expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) like

```
1,3,6,7,... * * * * * *
```

to schedule execution on specific intervals, in this case on seconds 1, 3, 6 and 7 past every minute, hour, day, year.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your schedule can be defined as a [cron expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression), then you **could try using [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation#current-product-documentation)**. Obviously it might mean adding a dependency that you don't already have, but it is a mature and well used library and it is designed specifically to execute tasks based on a more complex schedule than simply periodic.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Quartz. 
But if you don't want to introduce any dependencies you could use an executor. It's newer and better than timer task.
Check this example

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Task implements Runnable
{       
    private int delay = 0;

    public Task(int delay) 
    {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void registerNextExecution()
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledThreadPool.schedule(this, ++delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Execution at " + new Date());
        registerNextExecution();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I believe it's a good starting point.